# How can i create a CMFCRibbonEdit with SpinButtons and UDS_NOTHOUSANDS

Tags: mfc, ribbon

I want to use a CMFCRibbonEdit with SpinButtons in my ribbonbar. Therefor i call CMFCRibbonEdit::EnableSpinButtons(0, 10000). The Problem is, that the protected function CMFCRibbonEdit::CreateSpinButton() do `m_pWndSpin->Create()` without UDS_NOTHOUSANDS. How can i add the up-down control style UDS_NOTHOUSANDS later? There is only `m_pWndSpin->GetStyle()` but not function like SetStyle().

Do someone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is not SetStyle but there is a CWnd::ModifyStyle...

Comment: maybe this functions, but i not even have access to CMFCRibbonEdit::m_pWndSpin. "C2027, use of undefined type" occurs

Comment: CMFCRibbonSpinButtonCtrl is declared in the afxribbonedit.cpp file.  It is derived from CMFCSpinButtonCtrl. So you may be able to use reinterpret_cast and cast the pointer to CMFCSpinButtonCtrl*

Comment: Thanks, i implemented this reinterpret_cast, GetStyle after ModifyStyle shows the expected style, but in my application the thousands-dot is still visible. Here is my code-snippet:  CreateSpinButton(pWndEdit, pWndParent);
 CMFCSpinButtonCtrl* pSpinButtonCtrl = reinterpret_cast<CMFCSpinButtonCtrl*> ( m_pWndSpin );
 DWORD dwStyleBefore = pSpinButtonCtrl->GetStyle();
 pSpinButtonCtrl->ModifyStyle( 0, UDS_NOTHOUSANDS );
 DWORD dwStyleBehind = pSpinButtonCtrl->GetStyle();

Comment: The thousands dot is in your edit Control. Only when the Spincontrol is in Action it will modify the edit Control. Just changing the spin control will not Change the Content of the edit Control.

Comment: sorry, i do not understand this. If i press the spincontrol after modifying, the thousands dot will still be repainted. How can i remove this permanent?

Comment: Seams that modifing the style after the control is created, doesn't change the behaviour. This happens for some controls. Sorry than I have no more idea. Check with Spy++ if the style was really set...

Comment: Spy++ lists the style UDS_NOTHOUSANDS after modifying but the behaviour is not modified :-(